# Generating urls using relative paths and query string

Tags: javascript

I'm using firebase as a backend. For my little pet project, users need to be authenticated and submit relevant information. The relevant is then used to populate a profile.html document. I'd like to add the firebase generated UID to the url via a query string, so the entire thing looks like web-address.com/profile?user=uid. All the ways I found on the internet involve adding query strings to urls use absolute urls instead of relative paths. Are there examples that append query strings to relative paths?

I'm not trying to get the uid from firebase, I already know how to do that. Again, my problem has everything to do with url construction.

Comment: Sure you can put that query string on a relative path.  Why couldn't you?

Comment: it's just that I could find any examples of it, so i wasn't sure it was possible

Comment: This falls under the "try it and see if it works" type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

location.search = "user=uid"

not sure why you want to add this to the querystring. Really makes your app a bit easier to hack. You should be storing your bearer token in IndexedDB or localStorage and adding it as a request header.

Comment: i'm trying to find out who to generate url dynamically, it probably won't say like that

Comment: well in your code you would either need to change the location.href and add your querystring or do what I am showing you here. That is how you set queryString parameters.